# possible to indicate absolute path in ruby's require?

Tags: ruby, cron

i discovered a problem when cron tries to run a ruby script which uses some library.

```
require "library"

#do some stuff
```

it complains about not being able to find library.rb

so i was wondering if i could do something like require "/var/dir/library.rb"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. You could also simply add the directory where your files are to the list of paths in `$:`, either with the `-I` argument, the RUBYLIB environment variable or just by doing `$: << 'some_directory'`.

Comment: sorry...how can i add the directory ?

Comment: for example - $: << '/var/dir/' or $LOAD_PATH << '/var/dir/'. "library" is a gem or independent file?

Answer (score 1):

if you're using 1.9
require_relative is your friend